# Different versions of jQuery on the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I always have trouble using multiple versions of jQuery on one page.

I try to create a div which is scrollable with a facebook like scrollbar. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm
And I want to add a checkbox (a button which I can toggle) which shows or hides annother div. 
http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

I get both of the examples to work sperately from each other but if I try it in a single document one of the two won't work anymore.

How do I use 2 different versions of jQuery in one document?

Is there a way to reduce the JQuery library to the functions I need? Loading 2 different versions of jQuery for 2 or 3 simple functions seems like an overkill for me.

Thank you

Comment: This is a _huge_ code smell, but you might be able to get away with doing what you want with [`$.noConflic()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Say what? Do you mean jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: *I always have trouble using multiple versions of jQuery on one page.* don't then?!

Comment: Also, **show some code!**

Comment: Do you have like jquery-1.11.0.min.js and jquery-2.1.0.min.js included in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about different jquery plugin

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use $j instead of $ in your jquery code.

this way you can avoid conflict

[Conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)